# Error while using >> operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The error looks like this (2nd last line):

```
Error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Complex()')|
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complex {
  private:
    int a, b;
  public:
    Complex(int x, int y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    Complex() {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &dout, Complex &a);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &din, Complex &a);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &dout, Complex &a) {
    dout << a.a << " + i" << a.b;
    return (dout);
}

istream& operator >> (istream &din, Complex &b) {
    din >> b.a >> b.b;
    return (din);
}

int main() {
    Complex a();
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Complex a();
```

This is a [vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You think it means "default-initialize the variable `a`, which has type `Complex`." However, the compiler parses it as "declare a function called `a` which takes no arguments and returns a `Complex` value."  The syntax is ambiguous: it could mean either, but the language prefers a function declaration to a variable declaration.

Therefore, `a` is a function, not a variable.

Indeed, there is no declared operator overload that takes a function, which is why you get the error.  Note the specific type called out in the error:

```
operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Complex()'
                                                   parens indicate a function ^^
```

To fix this, replace this line with one of these:

```
Complex a{}; // C++11 and later only; uniform initialization syntax
Complex a;   // All versions of C++
```

Neither of these are ambiguous; they can only be parsed as a variable declaration.

Comment: But i have made constructors for the same purpose. Why is it that it is giving error while passing nothing to constructor.

Comment: … or `auto a = Complex();` — there are a lot of arguments in its favour; foremost that, if used consistently, it completely removes the most vexing parse from consideration.

Comment: @OmkarArora Read the link. The declaration is a *function declaration*, not an object declaration.

Comment: @OmkarArora -- How would you write a declaration for a function called `a` that returns `Complex` and takes no arguments?  Wouldn't it look exactly like `Complex a();`?  See the issue?

Comment: @KonradRudolph One could make the same argument about uniform initialization. It also removes the most vexing parse from consideration by the use of curly braces.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I replaced the body of void arg constructor with cout<<"It works" and it worked correctly

Comment: @OmkarArora The problem is the declaration of `a` in `int main()`. This has nothing to do with the definition of `Complex::Complex()`.

Comment: @cdhowie No, because “uniform initialisation” *does not exist* — the name is a lie. It was a good idea but it was screwed up by giving it the same syntax as aggregate initialisation. The consensus at the moment is overwhelmingly that it was a mistake, and not to use it *except* to mean aggregate initialisation, or to prevent a narrowing conversion. “Always auto” really is the solution to all these problems. I’m increasingly convinced that the arguments against it are completely vacuous.